# Mysql finds deadlock for concurrent transactions that only insert a row

Tags: sql, mysql, transactions, sequelize.js

I have an API which runs the following transaction

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (...)
UPDATE tbl SET col=val WHERE id=$(aboverow)
```

I am inserting a new row first, with an auto incremented primary key. My ORM (sequelize)(node js) returns the primary key which I use to generate `val`. The second query updates a column and sets `val` there.

When I run 5-6 concurrent API calls, 2-3 of them fail with the error `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`.

From some research, this error should only appear if two transactions are stepping on each other. Therefore, there shouldn't be any deadlocks here as each transaction is inserting a whole new row and should, then, be independent of all other transactions.

With some logging, I have found that the deadlock consistently occurs in the `INSERT` step.

**Edit**: Adding the table schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE `subscription_invoice` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoiceId` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL COMMENT '{key}',
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=81 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The `invoiceId` column is calculated based on the values of `id` and `userId`. `id` is auto generated by the db so I am inserting the row first and then updating the `invoiceId`. I am doing the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in a transaction.

Comment: (1) Are you running both the INSERT and UPDATE within one transaction ? If not, then after the row in INSERTed it is available for other users.
(2) Is there a unique index on id column of tbl. If not, then it'll be doing a table scan and causing deadlock because of waiting for some other row

Comment: Both insert and update are run in the same transaction. The Id is the primary key so it has a unique index, I believe.

Comment: can you do a SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl ? Just want to see the table definition as @Luxato suggested.

Comment: @NandalalSeth I have added the table schema

Comment: One last info, can you do a - select @@innodb_autoinc_lock_mode;

this is what I'm looking at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes

Comment: "ORM...returns the primary key" -- How??

Comment: "I am doing the INSERT and UPDATE in a transaction." -- Is anything else in the transaction?  Such as the ORM retrieving the id?

Comment: @RickJames I do not know exactly. What I do know is that when I run the query, my ORM (sequelize) returns the primary key. There is nothing else database related in the transaction. Some 3rd party service calls are there but I need the transaction to fail if those calls fail so they have to be there.

Comment: Two things could be done:  Turn on the "general log" to see all the queries executed.  and/or  `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` to see some detail son the "lastest deadlock".

Answer (score 0):

What type of engine is your table **tbl** using? Is it **InnoDB** or **MyISAM**?

The difference between these two in terms of deadlocks:

InnoDB: InnoDB supports row-level locking, meaning that only the specific rows that are being changed are locked.

MyISAM: Table-level Locking: MyISAM uses table-level locking for write operations.

Try running following SQL command (If it is production please make a backup first) and try again with the API calls.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: It is already InnoDB